# regex to replace ``` {.bash} with ```bash

Tags: regex, vim

Within vim I'd like to replace all

````
``` {.foo}
````

with

````
```foo
````

`foo` can be anything.

```` :0,$ s/``` {\.([^}]+)}/```\1/ ```` doesn't do the trick. It results in an

````
 E486: Pattern not found: ``` {\.([^}]+)}
````

error. What regex can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `(` and `)` if you want to capture the group (otherwise it just represents opening/closing parenthesis). You also need to escape `+` if you want it to mean one-or-more.

You also need to add the `g` flag at the end to mean global-substitute (all occurrences in a line, not just the first one), unless `gdefault` is on (in which case the `g` actually removes the global flag). And you can also use `:%s` to mean `:0,$s`.

So :

````
:%s/``` {\.\([^}]\+\)}/```\1/g
````